# How Do I Make A Chart in Dynamics CRM that Groups by A Related Entity's Attribute?

Tags: xml, charts, dynamics-crm-2011

How can I groupby an attribute of another entity in xml charts?
I would like a chart of number appointments (y-axis) by CRM user (x-axis), with appointments grouped by accountcategorycode of account.
I am using a view that only displays appointments regarding accounts.

I have a chart to group appointments by account, which works well:

```
    <visualization>
      <visualizationid>{8CC67476-302B-E211-86B2-005056BD0001}</visualizationid>
      <name>Appointment by User Stacked by Rating</name>
      <primaryentitytypecode>appointment</primaryentitytypecode>
      <datadescription>
        <datadefinition>
          <fetchcollection>
            <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
              <entity name="appointment">
                <attribute groupby="true" alias="ownerid" name="ownerid" />
                <attribute groupby="true" alias="gp" name="regardingobjectid" />
                <attribute alias="accountref" name="regardingobjectid"          aggregate="count" />
                <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="regardingobjectid" alias="aa">
                    <attribute name="accountcategorycode" alias="code" aggregate="count" />
                </link-entity>
                 <filter type="and">
                    <condition attribute="activitytypecode" operator="eq" value="4201" />
                </filter>
              </entity>
            </fetch>
          </fetchcollection>
          <categorycollection>
            <category alias="ownerid">
              <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="accountref" />
              </measurecollection>
            </category>
          </categorycollection>
        </datadefinition>
      </datadescription>
      <presentationdescription>
        <Chart Palette="None" PaletteCustomColors="55,118,193; 197,56,52; 149,189,66; 117,82,160; 49,171,204; 255,136,35; 97,142,206; 209,98,96; 168,203,104; 142,116,178; 93,186,215; 255,155,83">
          <Series>
            <Series ChartType="StackedColumn" IsValueShownAsLabel="False" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40"></Series>
          </Series>
          <ChartAreas>
            <ChartArea BorderColor="White" BorderDashStyle="Solid">
              <AxisY LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181" IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">
                <MajorGrid LineColor="239, 242, 246" />
                <MajorTickMark LineColor="165, 172, 181" />
                <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
              </AxisY>
              <AxisX LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181" IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">
                <MajorTickMark LineColor="165, 172, 181" />
                <MajorGrid LineColor="Transparent" />
                <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
              </AxisX>
            </ChartArea>
          </ChartAreas>
          <Titles>
            <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59"></Title>
          </Titles>
        </Chart>
      </presentationdescription>
      <isdefault>false</isdefault>
    </visualization></visualization>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried exporting the chart (as you seem to have already done) and modify the fetchXML with a linked group by? I often reference the examples in this fetchXML helper page on aggregation syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#groupby_linked

Notice the example the link jumps to is groupby_linked and works as you'd expect. (move the groupby down into the field of your linked entity)

FetchXML may not allow multiple group-by's across entities, give it a try and you'll find out quite quickly if that is the case.